# Using PowerBI DirectQuery on a Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, powerbi

I am attempting to use PowerBI's `DirectQuery` mode for a query to a Linked Server (which is in fact a PostgreSQL 9.6.5 server over ODBC). Import mode works fine.

`DirectQuery` shows the data at first, but eventually fails with `Unexpected Error: Couldn't load the model schema associated with this report. Make sure you have a connection to the server, and try again.`.

I'm wondering if this is at all possible (`DirectQuery` to Linked Server) and if so, what I'm doing wrong, perhaps within my server object properties?

- PowerBI: 2.50.4859.782
- MSSQL: 13.0.1601.5
- PGODBC: 9.06.0500
- PostgreSQL: 9.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to drop this effort. Microsoft seems to imply that [Linked Servers are not compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/directquery-mode-ssas-tabular#data-sources-supported-for-directquery).